# Programming Scheduler. Can not get multiple queues working

Tags: c, list, queue, scheduler

I have been working on this scheduler project for a bit now for class. I have current come across something that I have been unable to find the problem. I could be missing it or it could just be a lack of sleep. I think it is taking place in the block of code called ###MANAGING WAITING###. When I get to time about 23 it just stars printing that things have finished their IO burst, when in reality there should only be 1 or 2 process in the waiting list. Someone how the waiting list is getting filled. I can't figure out why this is the case. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    //Scheduler Project


typedef struct PCB{
  int pID;
  int arrivalTime;
  int totalBurst;
  int cpuBursts[10];
  int ioBursts[10];
  int waited;
  int currentCPUBurst;
  int currentIOBurst;
  int burstsRemaining;
  struct PCB* next;
  struct PCB* prev;
}PCB;


//#####################Creating Queues#####################
//Init queue head and tail
PCB* iHead = NULL;
PCB* iTail = NULL;

//Ready queue head and tail
PCB* rHead = NULL;
PCB* rTail = NULL;

//Waiting list head and tail
PCB* wHead = NULL;
PCB* wTail = NULL;

int Timer = 0;
PCB* running = NULL;

void calculateProcessStats();

//#####################Enqueues#####################
//Adds item to the back of init queue
void iEnqueue(PCB* item)
{
  if(iHead == NULL)    //Queue is empty.
    iHead = iTail = item;
  else{
    iTail->next = item;
    item->prev = iTail;
    iTail = item;
    iTail->next = NULL;
  }
}

//Adds item to the back of ready queue
void rEnqueue(PCB* item)
{
  if(rHead == NULL)    //Queue is empty.
    rHead = rTail = item;
  else{
    rTail->next = item;
    item->prev = rTail;
    rTail = item;
    rTail->next = NULL;
  }
  printf("Process %d has arrived\n", rTail->pID);
}

//Adds item to the back of waiting list
void wInsert(PCB* item)
{
  if(wHead == NULL)    //List is empty is empty.
    wHead = wTail = item;
  else{
    wTail->next = item;
    item->prev = wTail;
    wTail = item;
    wTail->next = NULL;
  }
}


//####################Dequeues##########################
//Removes item from front/head of the queue
PCB* iDequeue()
{
  PCB* temp = iHead;
  if(iHead == NULL)    //Queue is empty.
    return 0;
  else if(iHead==iTail && iHead != NULL){     //Single PCB in queue
    //free(iHead);
    iHead = NULL;
  }
  else{     //Two or more PCBs in queue
    iHead = iHead->next;
    //free(temp);
    iHead->prev = NULL;
  }
  return temp;
}

//Removes item from front/head of the queue
PCB* rDequeue()
{
  PCB* temp = rHead;
  if(rHead == NULL)    //Queue is empty.
    return 0;
  else if(rHead==rTail && rHead != NULL){     //Single PCB in queue
    //free(rHead);
    rHead = NULL;
  }
  else{     //Two or more PCBs in queue
    rHead = rHead->next;
    //free(temp);
    rHead->prev = NULL;
  }
  return temp;
}

//Removes node passed to functions. This is working on a queue
void wRemove(PCB* item)
{
  PCB* temp = wHead;
  while(temp != NULL)
    {
      if((temp->next == NULL) && (temp->pID == item->pID)){
        wHead = NULL;
        wTail = NULL;
      }
      else if(temp->pID == item->pID){
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
      }
      temp = temp->next;
    }
}

//Prints init queue head to tail
void iPrintQueue()
{
  PCB* temp = iHead;
  while(temp != NULL){
    printf("pid=%d ", temp->pID);
    printf("N=%d ", temp->burstsRemaining);
    printf("Arrival Time=%d ", temp->arrivalTime);
    printf("cpuBursts:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      if(temp->cpuBursts[i] == 0)
        break;
      printf("%d ", temp->cpuBursts[i]);
    }
    printf("\n                         ioBursts:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      if(temp->ioBursts[i] == 0)
        break;
      printf("%d ", temp->ioBursts[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

//Prints ready queue head to tail
void rPrintQueue()
{
  PCB* temp = rHead;
  while(temp != NULL){
    printf("pid = %d ", temp->pID);
    printf("N=%d ", temp->burstsRemaining);
    printf("Arrival Time=%d ", temp->arrivalTime);
    printf("cpuBursts:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      if(temp->cpuBursts[i] == 0)
        break;
      printf("%d ", temp->cpuBursts[i]);
    }
    printf("\n                         ioBursts:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      if(temp->ioBursts[i] == 0)
        break;
      printf("%d ", temp->ioBursts[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  //argv[0] = scheduler.cc
  //argv[1] = input file to read from
  //argv[2] = scheduling algorithm
  //argv[3] = quantum
  //argv[4] = cost of full context switch

  //This section opens files and write it to init queue (iHead, iTail) 
  FILE *file = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  if (file != NULL){     //Continue until entire file is empty
    char line [64];
    int pidCounter = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL){     //Grabs first line and puts stores in line, loops
      char* token = strtok(line, " ");
      PCB* temp = malloc(sizeof(PCB));
      int tokenCounter = 1;
      int cpuBurstCounter = 0;
      int ioBurstCounter = 0;
      while(token){     //Loops on single line, each iteration is the next token
        if(tokenCounter == 1){
          temp->arrivalTime = atoi(token);
        }
        else if(tokenCounter == 2){
          temp->burstsRemaining = atoi(token);
        }
        else if(tokenCounter %2 == 1){     //Everything > 2 and odd (cpuBurst)
          temp->cpuBursts[cpuBurstCounter] = atoi(token);
          cpuBurstCounter++;
        }
        else {     //Everything > 2 and even (ioBurst)
          temp->ioBursts[ioBurstCounter] = atoi(token);
          ioBurstCounter++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");     //Moves onto next token
        tokenCounter++;
      }
      temp->pID = pidCounter;
      pidCounter++;
      temp->currentIOBurst = 0;
      temp->currentCPUBurst = 0;
      temp->waited = 0;
      iEnqueue(temp);
    }
    fclose (file);
  }
  else{
    perror (argv[1]);
  }


  if((strcmp(argv[2], "FCFS") == 0) && (argc == 3)){     //First Come First Served NonPreemptive Algorithm
    while(1){
      Timer++;
      int timeLeft;
      printf("Time=%d\n", Timer);

      //##########MANAGE READY QUEUE##########
      if(iHead != NULL){
        while(iHead->arrivalTime == Timer){
          rEnqueue(iDequeue());
        }
      }

      //##########MANAGE RUNNING##########
      //Should only be entered during first iteration and after running is finished or sent to wait
      if((running == NULL) && (rHead != NULL)){
        running = rDequeue();
        timeLeft = running->cpuBursts[running->currentCPUBurst];
      }
      //Should enter this every time this is something running
      if(running != NULL){
        if(timeLeft == 0){
          if(running->burstsRemaining <= running->currentCPUBurst){
            calculateProcessStats();
            free(running);
          }
          wInsert(running);
          running->currentCPUBurst++;
          printf("Process %d is waiting\n", running->pID);
          running=NULL;
        }
        else{
          timeLeft--;
          printf("Process %d is running\n", running->pID);
        }      
      }

      //##########MANAGE WAITING QUEUE##########
      PCB* wTemp = wHead;
      while(wTemp != NULL){
        wTemp->waited++;
        printf("pid=%d > ", wTemp->pID);

        /*
          if(wTemp->waited == wTemp->ioBursts[wTemp->currentIOBurst]){
          printf("Process %d has completed IO and returned to Ready state", wTemp->pID);
          wRemove(wTemp);
          }
        */
        wTemp = wTemp->next;
      }



      //Remove this to have entire scheduler run
      getchar();
      printf("________________________________________________________________\n");
    }    


  }
  else if((strcmp(argv[2], "FCFS") == 0) && (argc == 5)){     //First Come First Server Preemptive Algorithm
    //argv[3] = quantum
    //argv[4] = cost of full context switch
    printf("This is the code for FCFS Preemptive");

    int quantum = atoi(argv[3]);
    int csCost = atoi(argv[4]);
    for(int i = 0; i < quantum; i++){

    }

  }
  else if(strcmp(argv[2], "SJNFP") == 0){     //Shortest Job Next Algorithm
    printf("This is the code for SJNFP");
    //create a sort function for ready queue to keep queue sorted by cpuBursts[currentCPUBurst]
    //dequeue from ready queue into running
  }
  else{
    printf("Error: The algorithm for %s does not exist\n", argv[2]);
    printf("Please use FCFS or SJNFP or check number of parameters for FCFS\n");
  }

  //When all processes finish
  //printf("Finished\nCPU Utilization: Avg/Max TAT=%f/%f, Avg/Max Wait Time=%f/%f, Avg/Max Response Time=%f/%f\n", avgTAT, maxTAT, avgWaitTime, maxWaitTime, avgResponseTime, maxResponseTime)

  return 0;
}


void calculateProcessStats(){
  int TAT = Timer - running->arrivalTime;
  int burstTime = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < running->totalBurst; i++)
    burstTime += running->cpuBursts[i];
  int waitTime = TAT - burstTime;
  int ioTime = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < running->totalBurst-1; i++)
    ioTime += running->ioBursts[i];
  printf("Process %d terminated: TAT=%d, Wait Time=%d, I/O Wait=%d\n", running->pID, TAT, waitTime, ioTime);
}
```

Comment: It might serve you well to combine the enqueue, dequeue, etc. into one function each.

Comment: It looks like your wRemove function removes an item from the list, unless the item is the last item in the list, in which case it removes the entire list. Is this what you meant it to do?

Comment: That is not what I meant. It is supposed to remove and item from the list, and the second case was supposed to be if there was only one item in the list. Going to fix that now and see what happens.